# Mild mechanical sound when using the camera

Tags: camera

I have a Samsung S10e, with android 11.

Whenever I use the camera, I hear a very mild sound that *appears* as if it were produced by an actual mechanical displacement of parts, not coming from the speaker.
It is similar to the (old) point-and-shoot cameras when autofocusing.

1. **Is that possible?**
2. If so, **is there any way of confirming this?**
3. If the sound is "mechanical", **is that normal/expected, or is it a sign of something wrong (even if perhaps not serious)?** (see link below)

Notes:

1. *Shutter sound* and *Vibration feedback* are set to *Off*.
2. Sounds **are** produced, e.g., when I:

   - activate the Camera app
   - exit the Camera app
   - open settings in the camera app (with the cog)
   - exit settings in the camera app
   - change mode (photo, video, more, etc.)
3. Sounds **are not** produced when I take pictures
4. If I shake the phone I hear a mild noise as well (not exactly the same). It is louder if I shake it up and down, than if I shake it left-right. Perhaps related to [the OIS](https://www.samsung.com/latin_en/support/mobile-devices/do-you-hear-a-small-noise-from-inside-of-the-device-when-shaking-your-galaxy-phone/), but not sure...
5. Some people noticed similar clicks [here](https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/galaxy-s10-series/s10-clicking-sound-when-opening-camera-app/td-p/2039101), [here](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-5/736517-camera-making-weird-noise.html) and [here](https://www.valuewalk.com/2019/03/clicking-noise-from-galaxy-s10-normal/), not sure it is the same. Not sure if the S10e is expected to make that noise.
6. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/galaxys10/comments/b0acad/comment/eidhv2z/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) warns about upcoming failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm I could see a sort of a shutter opening and closing (but not fully) whenever the click is heard.

I am not sure if it is "likely the aperature of the adjustable lens adjusting for the current light in the shot." [(VerbumVeritum, Samsung Care Ambassador)](https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S-Phones/camera-lens-click-noise/td-p/472792), or the OIS as linked in the OP, or...

Hopefully it does not precede failure.